# ATL to MAD, 1 hour stop in PHL with terminal change - Do I have to go through security a second time?

Tags: short-connections, phl

I have a flight on AA from Atlanta to Madrid.  My booking lists a "stop" in Philadelphia for approximately one hour and 15 minutes.  I'm concerned because my itinerary lists arrival in PHL at terminal A but departure from terminal B, and the airline switches to Iberia.  Will I need to go through security again before leaving PHL?  I'm worried about the short stop time.

Comment: All the terminals at PHL are connected airside, and on the outbound things will be no different from a domestic connection; however, on the return trip, you will need to clear immigration, customs, and security screening after arrival.

Answer (score 2):

[The airport's website](http://www.phl.org/Pages/Passengerinfo/PHLOverview.aspx) says that "In the secure area past the security checkpoints, all terminals and gates are accessible," meaning you will not have to re-clear security. [A map](https://maps.phl.org/) is available on their website and shows that the gates are connected by a short hallway. An hour and 15 minutes is plenty of time.